# convertir un numero a horas y minutos

Tags: javascript, programación-funcional

quizá esta es una pregunta medio tonta pero no le encuentro lógica.
En un ejercicio me piden que convierta un numero a horas y minutos.

```js
const ToTime = (num) => {
    const numero = num / 60 / 60

    return console.log(`${numero}`);
}

ToTime(323500)
```

El numero pasado por parámetro lo divido entre 60 segundos y 60 minutos.

Hasta ahí todo bien, la hora es correcta pero los minutos no.

Se supone que al pasarle el num "323500" retorna "89 hour(s) and 51 minutes(s)"

pero en la función retorna "89.86111111111111" y al dividir "8611" entre 60s retorna "1.4333333333333333".

No pido que lo resuelvan sino que me ayuden a entender que estoy haciendo mal.
De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que te esta confundiendo es que no te has dado cuenta que 323500 son segundos. solo debes hacer la conversión es muy sencillo.

```js
const ToTime = (seg) => {
    let horas = Math.floor(seg / 3600);
    let minutos = Math.floor((seg - (horas * 3600)) / 60);
    return `${horas}h ${minutos}m`;
}

console.log(ToTime(323500))
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo sería esta:

```js
const ToTime = (segundos) => {
  const minutos = Math.floor(segundos / 60)
  const segundos_restantes = segundos - (minutos * 60)
  const horas = Math.floor(minutos / 60)
  const minutos_restantes = minutos - (horas * 60)
  return (horas + ' horas, ' + minutos_restantes + ' minutos, ' + segundos_restantes + ' segundos')
}

console.log(ToTime(323500))
```

donde hacemos los cálculos con [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) para que nos devuelva el divisor cada vez, y partiendo de el calculamos el resto (aunque usando el operador `%` tambien podríamos sacarlo, aunque terminaríamos usando *Math.floor* de nuevo en algún momento).

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [**`Math.floor()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) para que hagas los divisores y calcules las horas, minutos y segundos con el parámetro que reciba tu función, a cada uno de estos resultados vas juntando en tu `return`:

```js
const ToTime = (num) => {
  var horas = Math.floor(num / 3600);
  horas = horas < 10 ? '0' + horas : horas;
  var minutos = Math.floor((num / 60) % 60);
  minutos = minutos < 10 ? '0' + minutos : minutos;
  var segundos = num % 60;
  segundos = segundos < 10 ? '0' + segundos : segundos;
  return horas + ':' + minutos + ':' + segundos;
}

console.log(ToTime(323500));
```

Answer (score 0):

No se estaba devolviendo 2 valores, si quieres devolver 2 valores tienes que retornar 2 . En el codigo solo se esta retornando el resultado de dividir 2 veces entre 60.

```js
const ToTime = (num) => {
  const numero = num / 60 / 60
  var hora = Math.trunc(numero)
  var minutos = (numero % 1) * 60
  console.log(`${hora}`)
  console.log(`${minutos}`)
  return [hora, minutos];
}

console.log(ToTime(323500))
```